# Test that method is called with some parameters, among others

Tags: php, phpunit

I'm testing a method with phpunit and I have the following scenario:

- method 'setParameter' is called an unkown amount of times
- method 'setParameter' is called with different kinds of arguments
- among the various arguments method 'setParameter' MUST be called with a set of arguments.

I've tried doing it this way:

```
$mandatoryParameters = array('param1', 'param2', 'param3');
foreach ($mandatoryParameters as $parameter) {
    $class->expects($this->once())
        ->method('setParameter')
        ->with($parameter);
}
```

Unfortunately the test failed because before method is called with these parameters it is called with other parameters too. The error i get is:

```
Parameter 0 for invocation Namespace\Class::setParameter('random_param', 'random_value')
does not match expected value.
Failed asserting that two strings are equal.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `$this->at()` method.  You are overwriting your mock each time with your loop.

```
$mandatoryParameters = array('param1', 'param2', 'param3');
$a = 0;
foreach ($mandatoryParameters as $parameter) {
    $class->expects($this->at($a++);
        ->method('setParameter')
        ->with($parameter);
}
```

This will set your mock to expect `setParameter` to be called a certain number of times and each call will be with a different parameter.  You will need to know which call is the specific on for your parameters and adjust the number accordingly.  If the calls are not sequential, you can set a key for which index each param.

```
$mandatoryParameters = array(2 =>'param1', 5 => 'param2', 6 => 'param3');

foreach ($mandatoryParameters as $index => $parameter) {
    $class->expects($this->at($index);
        ->method('setParameter')
        ->with($parameter);
}
```

The index is zero based so remember to start your counting from 0 rather than 1.

http://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/phpunit-book.html#test-doubles.mock-objects.tables.matchers

Comment: And if I don't know exactly how many times the function will be called  there is no way I can check that it will be called, among the other calls, also with these parameters?

Comment: You don't need to know how many times the function will be called, but you do need to know at which point it will be.  And that should be the same for every run of your tests, so you will need to determine that.  Though with a test, you should also know exactly the number of times the function will be called as you should have control over the entire system under test and can provide it with data that will give you a know number of calls with consistent parameters.

Comment: at() is depreacated in PHPUnit 9.6.